# PIXI.js running out of memory while creating many font textures

Tags: leaflet, webgl, pixi.js

I'm using pixiOverlay (leaflet) to render various objects onto a map.  I'd like to add labels underneath markers; however, I'm running out of memory when attempting to do this.  There are about 50k markers and 50k labels.  The markers render fine, but when I add the following code to create textures for each of my labels, I get GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY in the console.

```
        var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer();
        $.each(layer.data, function(inx, site) {
            let t = new PIXI.BitmapText("       " + site.VALUE + "      ", {font: 'TitleFontBlack'});
            var fontTexture = PIXI.RenderTexture.create({width: t.width, height: t.height});
            renderer.render(t, fontTexture);
            t.destroy(true);

            let key = "mLabels_" + site.VALUE;
            if (!loader.resources[key])
                loader.add(key, fontTexture);
        });

        // In loader.load, create sprites from the textures (never gets there)
```

As per domis86's question, I determined the average width and height of each texture to be about 80 x 14.  Doing the math, and assuming 3 bytes per pixel for the bitmap (?), that means 3360 bytes per texture or 160MB for 50k textures.  I'm not sure how much WebGL memory is available, but I could see how that is stressing it.

Can anyone think of a better way to add lots of text to a PIXI container?

Comment: what are the values of `t.width` and `t.height` (avarage) ?

Comment: I edited the post with the information you requested.

Comment: can you try reducing number of labels to see how much of them will not generate this error?

Comment: another thing: can you try running it without markers? See how it changes memory - maybe they are the bottleneck? To see some overview of gpu memory you can use Chrome ["task manager"](https://www.howtogeek.com/437681/how-to-use-chromes-built-in-task-manager/) ("GPU memory" column)